# passing Array data dynamically in URL to call webapi method (C#)

Tags: c#, angularjs, arrays, json, asp.net-web-api

below is my json generated data from the backend

```
{"langs":[{"cisAreaId":100,"area":"Prog","name":"C#"},{"cisAreaId":110,"area":"Prog","name":"Java"},{"cisAreaId":120,"area":"Prog","name":"MS.NET languages(VB.NET,etc)"},{"cisAreaId":130,"area":"Prog","name":"MS Visual Languages (VB, C++, etc)"},{"cisAreaId":140,"area":"Prog","name":"Python"},{"cisAreaId":150,"area":"Prog","name":"Ruby"}]}
```

above data i copied to $scope.areas. 
Now in my view

```
<div ng-repeat="lang in areas.langs">
        <label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="lang.selected" value="{{lang.cisAreaId}}" /> {{lang.name}}</label>
    </div>
```

once user click the submit, I need to capture selected checkbox values and send it as JSON data.

```
    $scope.languageArray = [];
    angular.forEach($scope.areas.langs, function (lang) {
        if (lang.selected) $scope.languageArray.push({ "cisAreaId": lang.cisAreaId });
    });
    var data = JSON.stringify({
        languages: $scope.languageArray,
    });
```

it is forming the array like after selecting the two of the checkbox values

```
{"languages":[{"cisAreaId":110},{"cisAreaId":120}]}
```

From the above code how can I pass the above dynamic array in the URL to call the backend method

```
Angularjs Controller Code:    
XXXService.step2Form(data).then(function (results) {
            console.log(results.data); 
        }, function (error) {
            alert(error.data.message);
        });

service code:
var _step2Form = function (data) {
       return $http.post(serviceBase + 'api/feedback/Step2Data' + data , { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } });
        };
```

I have pass the data dynamically to the backend

```
public HttpResponseMessage Step2Data([FromBody] int[] languages)
```

but i am getting the error like this

```
http://localhost:53401/api/XXXX/Step2Data[object%20Object],[object%20Object] 404 (Not Found)
```

can anyone please tell me how to pass the array values dynamically in the url to call the webapi method.

Comment: You're passing it in via the url, not the body. Also, get rid of the complex object structure and just use an array of ids.

Comment: I tried pushing the id only, but the result will be [130,140] and the error URL is  http://localhost:53401/api/XXXXX/Step2Data130,140      404 (Not Found). I changed the method parameters in the backend as well   public HttpResponseMessage Step2Data([From Body] List<int> languages) and also removing the [FomBody] also.

Answer (score 2):

in `$scope.languageArray` you need to push just the id :

```
$scope.languageArray = [];
angular.forEach($scope.areas.langs, function (lang) {
   if (lang.selected) $scope.languageArray.push(lang.cisAreaId);
});
var data = JSON.stringify({
     languages: $scope.languageArray,
});
```

Comment: try to replace [FromBody] int[] languages by [FromBody] List<int> languages

Comment: I tried pushing the id only, but the result will be [130,140] and the error URL is  http://localhost:53401/api/XXXXX/Step2Data130,140      404 (Not Found). I changed the method parameters in the backend as well   public HttpResponseMessage Step2Data([From Body] List<int> languages)

Comment: add an [HttpPost] to your action : 

[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Step2Data([FromBody] int[] languages)

Comment: Yes I added already
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Step2Data([FromBody] List<int> languages)
I guess there is something we need to change in the URL part.

Comment: Yes. Replace + with , : $http.post(serviceBase + 'api/feedback/Step2Data , data...

Comment: Thank you I am able to hit the method now